# C# convert binary data to string?

Tags: c#

I was just going through the registry retrieving values and binary is making my file outputer fall.

I was wondering how could I convert Subkey.getValue(value[i]) into a String if the Value type is binary?

Comment: A String of what?  In other words, how do you want to do the conversion?  Or, would it be better to just write the byte[] to a file?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 is a typical method of converting binary to/from a string...

Comment: What is the return type of the SubKey.getValue function? Is it binary or bit?? There is no binary data type in C# AFAIK

Comment: GetValue returns an Object.  However, for `REG_BINARY`/`RegistryValueKind.Binary` that object will be a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the type is binary, the assumption would be that the byte array (which it will be, as Matthew mentioned) isn't going to be of any 'normal' string encoding type (ascii, utf16, etc), so I don't think you're asking to convert it to one of those (if you were, just use Encoding.Foo.ToString)

Since you want it as a string, it then depends on what kind of string you want.  If you just want some string and don't care about the particular format, I'd just use the BCL's BitConverter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx